# is the inner function a property of outer function?

Tags: javascript, function

```
Function.prototype.test = function(){return "F"}
function hh(){var x="xx";function test(){return "f"}}

print(hh.test());
```

the result is "f", does that mean the inner function is a property of outer function?

== updated my code, but the result is still "f". !_!

Comment: The result cannot be `'f'`. `hh.test` is `undefined`, because the inner function is a private function.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your results: http://jsfiddle.net/dHPQX/ It throws an error *hh.test is not a function*. `hh` does not have a property `test`.

Comment: The actual error is that hh.test is not a function, but yeah this is cause it's private to hh.

Comment: Who upvoted this broken question? >.<

Comment: guys, "f" is what I got without any error, I am using Mozilla® SpiderMonkey (JavaScript–C) Engine for js 1.5 implementation

Comment: @Phil Parsons, test will not be defined in the global scope. It's only visible inside hh(). You comment about the "missing" var is also incorrect, it's a function...

Comment: @Nikoloff you're right! for some reason I thought the code read `test = function ()...` - my bad :$

Comment: I tried version 1.8, and there it outputs `F`. So maybe it is a problem with the version you are using.

Answer (score 4):

The result should be an error - and at least in Chrome, it is.

`test` inside `hh` is a local function, and it should not be accessible from outside.

As for `Function.test`, it is a property of `Function` - not a member of *all* functions. If you actually want to make something a member of all functions, it needs to be added to `Function.prototype`

Comment: actually what the engine I used is Mozilla® SpiderMonkey (JavaScript–C) Engine, it produced the "f" result, so, is it engine specific behavior?

Answer (score 1):

You actually managed to get a result from this code? You are trying to print the result.

`hh.test` will be undefined as `test` is being defined privately to hh. Defining test on the prototype `Function.prototype.test` would return 'F' from `hh.test` in this instance.

Comment: yes, you are right, but that what the code exactly gave to me, I am using Mozilla® SpiderMonkey (JavaScript–C) Engine, not sure if this syntax is supported by this engine?